# Long TextViews Pushes Element off the screen in LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have three TextViews in a LinearLayout arranged one beside the other. However, if the text in the middle TextView becomes too long, the left TextView is pushed off the screen.

I do *not* want to use android:weight since I do not want to predefine a fix value for the ratio between the three TextViews.

How to fix it?

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_left"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="LEFT"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_middle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#aaaaaa"
        android:text="This is a very very long text which is so long that it wraps but unfortunatelly also pushes the TextView with ID item_right off the screen."
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RIGHT"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use a scroll view as root .

Answer (score 1):

Try by setting `weights` to each `TextView` on that way each `TextView` will have own space in `LinearLayout` and instead of pushing right `TextView` of screen text will wrap instead for example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_left"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="LEFT"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_middle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#aaaaaa"
    android:text="This is a very very long text which is so long that it wraps but unfortunatelly also pushes the TextView with ID item_right off the screen."
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_right"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="RIGHT"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

You don't need to give to each `TextView` equal space you can for example give to middle `TextView` more space manipulating `weights` for example:
`android:layout_weight="2"` And wrapping all in `ScrollView` you will prevent issue of invisible text if text length is bigger then screen size.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_left"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="LEFT"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_middle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#aaaaaa"
        android:text="This is a very very long text which is so long that it wraps but unfortunatelly also pushes the TextView with ID item_right off the screen."
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RIGHT"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```